# RDS Snapshot Location for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have Configured AWS RDS Postgresql 9.5 few months back. My DB size is almost **1TB**. WHen ever i take a manual snapshot of my DB it is showing in Snapshot tab. Wanted to know the physical location of these files stored. My overall DB size is 2TB, I have taken some 20 snapshots. Where are these snapshot stored locally?

NOTE: I have not configured any S3 manually to store this snapshot.

Comment: I don't think you have access directly to the snapshots.  You need to restore them into a new db instance to access them.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the snapshot data is stored in Amazon S3. However, it is not accessible to you (it is stored in a bucket owned and managed by the Amazon RDS service).

You can only interact with the snapshots via the Amazon RDS console and API.

**Snapshot Pricing**

From [Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL Pricing – Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/pricing/):

> - There is no additional charge for backup storage up to 100% of your total database storage for a region. (Based on our experience as database administrators, the vast majority of databases require less raw storage for a backup than for the primary dataset, meaning that most customers will never pay for backup storage.)
> - After the DB instance is terminated, backup storage is billed at $0.095 per GiB-month.
> - Additional backup storage is $0.095 per GiB-month.

Comment: thanks for your update, But any idea how much data it can take in? there are many snapshots ive  created what would be the pricing for those?